# Stop peer dependencies using minor version (^) from updating in project

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, semantic-versioning, package-lock.json

I have a project in which the client's policy in the CI pipelines ignore `package-lock.json` file and **always install everything from scratch**.

The issue with this is that sometimes, everything works locally but then it fails in the pipelines, as the versions are different. To avoid this, **I removed the `package-lock.json` completely from the project.**

But now, even though **I have all my versions with exact numbers**, all of the libraries I use have the **versions with minor updates (using `^`)**, and that is causing a lot of issues.

The last issue we're having is that a plugin is requiring `@emotion/memoize` at version `0.8.1` and it says it doesn't exist:

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @emotion/memoize@^0.8.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I'm not using that library at all and I haven't changed anything in the code, but now the CI pipeline is failing because one of my dependencies has a peer dependency which uses that library and it seems it's specified the wrong version.

**Is there a way in which I can avoid dependencies from updating their dependencies even when they use minor version updates (`^`)?**

**Or can I specify a version somehow for a dependency on my main `package.json` file and force dependencies to use that version and avoid unwanted updates?**

Please, understand that I can't change client's policies in their pipelines.

Thank you.